# eclipse coloring : what is the pref item for background color of all occurrences of selection

Tags: eclipse, colors, themes

In Eclipse, when a identifier ( function name or variable etc ) is clicked, the
background of that identifier and all other occurrences of that identifier are given
a different background color.

Can anybody tell me, what is the preference item for changing background color for this.

( last this remaning in my dark eclipse settings ).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a section titled **Annotations** that allows you to configure the background color for **Occurrences**.  You can find it in Preferences under *General* -> *Editors* -> *Text Editors* -> *Annotations*.

I had to restart Eclipse to see my changes--a simple **Apply** on the Preferences window wasn't enough (using Eclipse SDK 3.4.1).

Comment: For me too, without restart. But I would never find out this is inside Annotations -- it does not make much sense... +1 for the "discovery".

Comment: +1 This also worked for me, and though I was specifically looking for "JavaScript Occurrences", it was still in Preferences under General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations.  I didn't have to restart for it to take effect.

Comment: Is it possible to change the priority of them? The *Warnings* annotation type looks to always overlap the *Occurrences* one in the overview ruler no matter how dark or saturated colour I choose for the *Occurrences*.