# Eclipse highlight occurrences, right column marker color

Tags: java, eclipse, colors, color-scheme

Similar, but different to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671219/eclipse-coloring-what-is-the-pref-item-for-background-color-of-all-occurances-o):

I use highlight occurrences a lot, but sometimes I'm irritated by how hard it is to see the little grey-ish rectangles on the rightmost side of the editor - to the right of the scrollbar.

Is there any way to change the color of these markers - looking in `General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations` gives me control over the colors of annotations, but it doesn't seem to work for find occurrences.  Also, I can right click on the markers and it sends me to the same dialog, but the color still seems to do nothing.

Any ideas?

I'm using the Java editor.

Comment: Ok, this can be closed.  The color does work, I just had to open a new editor to have it take effect.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It used to take a restart(!) for the color modification to change for certain editors! (as [in 2006](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.jdt/msg17750.html)), due to a bug in Platform UI.
But for current edition (3.4.x, 3.5.1), the `General->Editors->Text Editors->Annotations` preference page (the `Occurrences` item) should be enough to change on the spot any color settings you want.
After that, it depends on the nature of the editor (PDT editors used to miss that feature, until [bug 166178](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=166178) was fixed)

Comment: Worked for me. For those who use C++ editor its in the same place under C/C++ Occurrences

Answer (score 9):

In Kepler 4.3 we can change the colour of occurrence as follow:

```
General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations -> Occurrences
```

[image]

Comment: It should be noted that as of 4.4, changing the color of occurrences still requires closing and reopening the editor.  (By contrast, changing the color of *write* occurrences takes effect immediately.)

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I found it while looking for an answer. Now, I've just found an easier way to change the colour that some people might find useful. Just right-click on the little colour rectangle and you get a context menu for Preferences, which takes you to the right place for changing the colour of that particular marker.

Answer (score 3):

A new feature of Juno (Eclipse 4.2) may also help here:

- Go To General → Editors → Text Editors → Accessibility
- Check *Use saturated colors in overview ruler*

Also see the [what's new](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.2-201206081400/news/eclipse-news-part1.html#Platform-use-saturated-colors) entry about this.

Answer (score 0):

Click **Toggle Mark Occurrences** icon:

[image]