# change in colour of highlights does not stick

Tags: pydev

I am trying to change the colour of the highlights of occurrences, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670634/eclipse-highlight-occurrences-right-column-marker-color).

I can do this, and it works. However, when I restart LiClipse (on osx 10.9.3, liclipse v0.99), the previous colour is back.

I tried changing the permissions on /Applications/liclipse, but this did not help. -- what else could I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LiClipse manages the color scheme itself.

So, if you want you can use it to change the colors (preferences > appearance > color theme > edit theme > occurrenceIndication).

Now, if you want to manage those yourself after the initial LiClipse set, in preferences > appearance > color theme you can change 'reapply settings on restart' to 'dont reapply settings on restart.